# Maybe bug in Mathematica - Graph export error

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

Executing the following lines of code draw some binary graph.

```
    BDDPlot[depth_, funValues_] :=
    Module[{BDDLabels, INVEdges},
    BDDLabels = Thread[Range[2^depth - 1] -> Join[Alphabet[][[Floor[Log2[#]] + 1]] & /@ Range[2^(depth - 1) - 1], funValues]]; 
    INVEdges = 
     Flatten[ Map[{#1 \[UndirectedEdge] #1*2 -> 
        Dashed, {#1 \[UndirectedEdge] #1*2 + 1 -> {Thick, Black}}} &,
           Range[2^(depth - 1)]]];
    CompleteKaryTree[depth, 
      VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", 
       VertexSize -> Large,
        VertexLabels -> 
         MapAt[Placed[#, Center] &, 
          BDDLabels, {All, 2}], EdgeStyle -> INVEdges ,
          VertexLabelStyle -> {Large}, VertexStyle -> White, ImageSize -> Large]]

    BDDPlot[3, {0, 1, 0, 0}] (* Drawing BDD example *)
```

Then right click on draw and choose "save graph as", results in the following error:

```
Set::write: Tag Inherited in Inherited[State] is Protected.
```

Any idea what is the source of the error and how to overcome this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try defining your vertex labels and edge styles separately.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem.
There is another way to export the graph, but still the issue i mentioned maybe reported as bug in Mathematica.
Another way to export the for those who bothers graph: 
`Export["~/graph.pdf", BDDPlot[3, {0, 1, 0, 0}]];`

However I won't close this issue since the problem wasn't solved yet.

Comment: If I scrape-n-paste your block of code into a new empty notebook then MMA says there is a missing `]`,

Comment: One of the lines was missed, problem was fixed, the code should run.

Comment: (1) Do report the bug to Wolfram http://www.wolfram.com/support/ (2) Use `Export` to work around the problem.

Comment: "However I won't close this issue since the problem wasn't solved yet."  StackOverflow is not an issue tracker. If you find a bug in a software, report it to the developer directly. (Please do it for the sake of everyone who might be affected by the same bug.) You mention the `Export` workaround yourself.  What other answer do you expect?

Comment: I waited for a second opinion, to make sure it is a bug. Finding bug in Mathematica isn't so common and error message at this case misled. Most of the time the problem is located at the user's side. Thank you for the approval and bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug was reported to Mathematica.

The solution is: `Export["~/graph.pdf", BDDPlot[3, {0, 1, 0, 0}]];`